# assign Gridview column on client side and it shows up, but the text show black on codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Good Morning.

I have a gridview.  I want to assign text to one of the columns.
The text shows up in the grid.  But at codebind, the text is blank.  Sincerely appreciate any help.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<Columns>
    .....
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="+/-" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="w2do" HeaderText="What2Do" />
        ......
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Script:**

```
function xx(grid) {
    for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
        row = grid.rows[i];
        row.cells[1].val("+");      // give error
            row.cells[1].Text = "+";    // this way, text doesn't show up inthe grid.
            row.cells[1].innerHTML = "+";   // text shows up in the grid; but when I'm ready to use it at code behind, the text is not there.
    }
}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in <asp:GridView {
    row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();       // text is empty

}
```

Comment: Correction.  It's row.Cell[0], not row.Cell[1].

Comment: You cannot add data to a grid client side and expect the data to be available in a PostBack. That is not how it works. If you want to add data you have to use another method.